# Add root element to existing Json in Go lang

Tags: go

I'm trying to add string "Employee" to my existing JSON response. Also, we need to be able to generate this version of json based on an user condition. Only if the user condition is met, I need to generate second version of json with string "Employee" added. If not the first version without string "Employee" should be generated. How can I achieve it with out updating the existing `struct` and how can I check this with if clause to check for the condition and then generate json based on it?

Below is my existing json response in go

```json
[
   {
      "EmpId":{
         "String":"ABCD",
         "Valid":true
      },
      "Department":{
         "Float64":0,
         "Valid":true
      }
   }
]
```

How can I get my json response like below with out changing existing struct based on input parameter?

```json
{
   "Employee":[
      {
         "EmpId":{
            "String":"ABCD",
            "Valid":true
         },
         "Department":{
            "Float64":0,
            "Valid":true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my code:
Step 1: model folder

```
type EmployeeWithRoot struct {
    Employee []Employee
}
type Employee struct {
    EmpNbr     sql.NullString  `json:"EmpNbr"`
    DateofJoin      sql.NullString   `json:"DateofJoin"`
        DeptId  sql.NullString  `json:"DeptId"`
        DeptName sql.NullString  `json:"DeptName"`
}
```

Step 2: code folder

```
func GetEmpDetails(logRequestId string, logNestedLevel int, EmpNbr string, DateofJoin string) ([]model.EmployeeWithRoot, error) {
    logFunctionFunctionName := "code.GetEmpDetails"
    logStartTime := time.Now()
    logNestedLevel++
    defer configurations.TimeTrack(logFunctionFunctionName, logRequestId, logStartTime, logNestedLevel)
    rows, err := db.Query(utils.SELECT_OF_EMP_AGGR, EmpNbr, DateofJoin, DeptId, DeptName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var e []model.EmployeeWithRoot
    for rows.Next() {
        var x model.EmployeeWithRoot
        err := rows.Scan(&x.Employee.EmpNbr, &x.Employee.DateofJoin, &x.Employee.DeptId,&x.Employee.DeptName)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        e = append(e, x)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return e, nil
}
```

STEP 3: API folder

```
Employee, err := code.GetEmpDetails(logRequestId, logNestedLevel, EmpNbr, DateofJoin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    marshalDataForRequestContentType(logRequestId, logNestedLevel, w, r, Employee)
```

I'm getting the below error.

x.Employee.EmpNbr undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method EmpNbr)
x.Employee.DateofJoin undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DateofJoin)`enter code here`
x.Employee.DeptId undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DeptId)
x.Employee.DeptName undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DeptName)

Comment: `[]model.Employee` is a slice (so could contain 0-many `Employee` records) this means that trying to get its `EmpNbr` makes no sense (you could do `x.Employee[0].EmpNbr` assuming the slice had an element but that is not what you want here). Your extra comments are a totally different question (initial question was JSON now you are retrieving data from a database). Quick answer - you should probably be scanning into an `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're just wrapping it it an outer object, I don't see any reason you'd need to change the existing struct, just wrap it in a new one. I'll have to make some guesses/assumptions here since you've only shown the JSON and not the Go code that produces it, but assuming your existing JSON is produced by marshaling something like `var response []Employee`, the desired JSON could be produced in your condition by marshaling instead:

```
json.Marshal(struct{Employee []Employee}{response})
```

Working example: https://go.dev/play/p/vwDvxnQ96G_2

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```
func addRoot(json string) string {
    return `{ "Employee":` + json + `}`
}
```

[Run an example on the GoLang playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Y88cfI18Vg-).

Here's the code if you are working with []byte instead of string:

```
func addRoot(json []byte) []byte {
    const prefix = `{ "Employee":`
    const suffix = `}`
    result := make([]byte, 0, len(prefix)+len(json)+len(suffix))
    return append(append(append(result, prefix...), json...), suffix...)
}
```

[Run this example on the GoLang playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Z72niAfYipV).

Comment: Also, we need to be able to generate this version of json based on an user condition. Only if the user condition is met, I need to generate second version of json with string "Employee" added. If not the first version without string "Employee" should be generated. How can I check this with if clause to check for the condition and then generate json based on it?

Comment: @sri Use an if statement to conditionally execute code: `if yourcondition { j = addRoot(j) `.  If that does not solve the problem, explain more about what it means to meet the condition.

Answer (score -1):

If you have some JSON in a byte slice (`[]byte`) then you can just add the outer element directly - e.g. ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/9g-ase7YBO7)):

```golang
existingJSON := []byte(`[
      {
         "EmpId":{
            "String":"ABCD",
            "Valid":true
         },
         "Department":{
            "Float64":0,
            "Valid":true
         }
      }
   ]`)
b := bytes.NewBufferString(`{"Employee":`)
b.Write(existingJSON)
b.WriteString(`}`)
fmt.Println(string(b.Bytes()))
```

If this is not what you are looking for please add further details to your question (ideally your attempt as a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Also, we need to be able to generate this version of json based on an user condition. Only if the user condition is met, I need to generate second version of json with string "Employee" added. If not the first version without string "Employee" should be generated. How can I check this with if clause to check for the condition and then generate json based on it?

Comment: Please provide sample code; without this we are forced to make assumptions and provide incomplete answers.

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments; please delete your comments and edit the question (assuming that one of the other answers has not already provided you with a way forward).